# A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> in Talend Job

Tags: github, talend, github-api, rest-client

I'm trying to get data from github with this talend job,[image]
[image]

But i couldn't get the data, because it is showing some error.

```
A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root><root><id>75978949</id><name>Samplerepository</name>
```

how can i resolve this issue?

This is my output value, when i tested the URL with browser;

```
[
  {
    "id": 59002981,
    "name": "awesome-ciandcd",
    "full_name": "sample/awesome-ciandcd",
    "owner": {
      "login": "sample",
      "id": 354018,
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/354018?v=4"

    },
    "private": false,
    "html_url": "https://github.com/sample/awesome-ciandcd",
    "description": "continuous integration and continuous delivery",
    "fork": true,
    "mirror_url": null,
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "forks": 0,
    "open_issues": 0,
    "watchers": 2,
    "default_branch": "master"
  }
]
```

I have modified the job like, **tRESTClient --> tFileOutputJSON** and stored value like below,

```
[{"string":null,"body":
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <root>
        <id>59002981</id>
        <name>awesome-ciandcd</name>
        <full_name>sample/awesome-ciandcd</full_name>
        <owner>
            <login>sample</login>
            <id>354018</id>
        </owner>
        <private>false</private>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <forks_count>0</forks_count>
        <default_branch>master</default_branch>
    </root>
    <root>
        <id>35035177</id>
        <name>yell-adapters-gelf</name>
        <full_name>sample/yell-adapters-gelf</full_name>
        <owner>
            <login>sample</login>
            <id>354018</id>
        </owner>
        <private>false</private>
        <forks>0</forks>
        <open_issues>0</open_issues>
        <watchers>0</watchers>
        <default_branch>master</default_branch>
    </root>
</root>,"statusCode":200}]
```

After that, created a job, **tFileInputJSON --> tExtractJSONFileds --> tLogRow** , but it is throwing error is:  **fail to parse the json file : C:/Desktop/Output.json**

How to handle this issue?

Comment: Seems like the API is returning XML and not JSON.

Comment: I tried with tXMLMap instead of tExtracJSONFileds, but that also throwing error like, HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type. But i added the content type in advance settings of tRESTClient.

Comment: In my post i have added output value of the URL. That is not a XML format.

Answer (score 1):

It's throwing error because response is a JSON array not a simple json object.

You can store the response into a json file. Read the file using tFileInputJSON and then you can extract the values using tExtractJSONFields.

Below is the sample job (I have used above sample data)

[image: sample job]

[sample job[image: ][1]]

Comment: After store the result in json output file, tried like above example. But it is throwing an error, fail to parse the json file : C:/Desktop/Output.json

Comment: If i have choose Read By as JsonPath without loop, one record has been generated. But i need to get all the values. 19 counts

Comment: are you getting 19 records in one JSONArray or 19 different JSONArray?

Comment: in second case you can generate 19 temp files and iterate over them. In first case you just need to change your query.  like in tFileInputJSON change read by to jSONPath, Loop JSONquery could be "$[*]", JSONpath query could be "$" and no changes should be required in tExractJSONFields

Comment: i have single JSONArray with 19 records

Comment: so the solution suggested in above comment should work for you !!

Comment: I have one more question, if i execute the URL via browser, it is giving JSONArray response. But the same url used in talend tRESTClient & checked in tLogRow, it is giving XML format data. How is this possible?

Comment: what dataType have you set in request header of your tRestClient component ?

Comment: This URL only used in the tRESTClient component, https://api.github.com/users/sample/repos

Answer (score 0):

Because its not a JSONObject
Its a JSONArray

Put loop path query in tExtractJsonfield component